# How to merge styles defined in defaultProps with inline styles in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styling

I have to define some default styling on the Text component provided by React. I am doing this like:

```
 @ts-ignore
 Text.defaultProps.style = {fontWeight: '100'}
```

I have to define some other styling on the Text component which is specific to where the Text component is used. But when I try to provide style in Text component using inline style, it seems to override the defaultProps.style that I had.

```
<Text style={{color: 'white'}}> // this text only has white color but not fontWeight that was defined in defaultProps.
```

Is there a way to merge both of them while using the Text component provided by react?

I have tried the following:

```
<Text style={{...this.props.style, color:'white'}}>
```

I have also tried this:

```
<Text style={[this.props.style, {color:'white'}]} >
```

Both of these don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The styles are getting overwritten because the defaults are not *merged* with styles.  If no styles are passed in, the default will be used, but if you pass in any styles, the default object is overwritten with the new style object.

Generally I would discourage you from setting default props on a built-in component.  It can make the code hard to follow, and it's not helping you in the way you want.  Besides, React was built for this.  Here's a Typescript example:

```js
interface Props {
  style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
  children?: string;
}

const defaultStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  default: {
    color: 'black',
  }
});

const MyText: React.FC<Props> = ({ style, children }) => {
  return <Text style={[ defaultStyles.default, style ]}>{children}</Text>
}
```

When you put styles into an array as above, they will get progressively merged from beginning to end.  So if you write

```js
  <MyText style={{ color: 'white' }}>Text</MyText>
```

the prop style will overwrite the color in your default style.  However, if you do

```js
  <MyText style={{ textDecoration: 'underline' }}>Text</MyText>
```

the final stylesheet will be merged, and have both the `color` and `textDecoration` properties.  See [the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/style) for more.

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting but it is what I expected. Do you know if there's a way to merge the two without changing the built-in component. I am working on a codebase where I can't create a new custom component and change all the Text components. Any recommendation would be appreciated.